# When is the property of being a dense functor cancellable?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, functors

Let $\mathcal C \to \mathcal D \to \mathcal E$ be a pair of functors. Assume that $\mathcal C$ is dense in $\mathcal E$. Is then $\mathcal D$ also dense in $\mathcal E$? One definition of denseness is that the nerve, that is the restricted Yoneda embedding $\mathcal E \to \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal C)$ is fully faithful. We want that the same holds with $\mathcal D$ instead of $\mathcal C$. Everything fits into a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathcal E @>>> \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal D)\\ @.     {_{}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVV\\  @. \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal C), \end{CD}$$

where the vertical functor is the restriction. Obviously the diagonal functor is faithful because the top is faithful but from there I would need something like the restriction being faithful for example, which is not always the case. So is there a counterexample to the question or some (reference to a) proof?

Comment: To be clear, you take the composite $C\to E$ to be a functor realising $C$ as dense in $E$, and want to know if this implies $D\to E$ realises $D$ as dense in $E$?

Comment: @FShrike Correct. If you mean that the functors are inclusions, then this would be sufficient for me. Or you can just take the definition of a dense functor which doesn‘t necessarily require subcategories as in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful reference for cancellability of dense functors is §5.2 of Kelly's [Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html). For instance, in your example, if $\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is essentially surjective, or if $\mathcal D \to \mathcal E$ is fully faithful, then density of $\mathcal C \to \mathcal D \to \mathcal E$ implies density of $\mathcal D \to \mathcal E$ (Proposition 5.11 and Theorem 5.13 ibid.).

Comment: See http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf#page94 for the correct page in the PDF file.